# Can a bisection search guess that the user guessed the highest value?

Tags: python, bisection

I am trying to make the computer use a bisection search to guess a number I entered that is from 0 to 100. Now, for all the numbers I enter the computer can guess within 7 tries, all except 100, where it goes into an infinite loop. I know why that happens, it's because I have int(high+low)/2 so the closest the program would get to 100 would be 99.5 ( high=100, low=99) which would be rounded to 99. so the program will keep guessing 99. How can I modify my code so that it deals with this, without have to specifically guess the number 100 using an if statement?

```
print("This is a bisection search, which I hopefully am going to beat. HAHAHA!")
for i in range(99999**9):
    high=100
    low=0
    number_of_searches=1
    print('enter a guess between 0 and 100')
    user_input =  int(input())
    
    guess = int((high+low)/2)
    while user_input != guess:
        if guess>user_input:
            high=guess
        else:
            low=guess 
        number_of_searches+=1
        guess=int((high+low)/2)
        
    print (" your number was found in ",number_of_searches, "search
```

es")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set high to 101 and it will find it.

```
print("This is a bisection search, which I hopefully am going to beat. HAHAHA!")
for i in range(99999**9):
    high=101
    low=0
    number_of_searches=1
    print('enter a guess between 0 and 100')
    user_input =  int(input())

    guess = int((high+low)/2)
    while user_input != guess:
        if guess>user_input:
            high=guess
        else:
            low=guess 
        number_of_searches+=1
        guess=int((high+low)/2)

    print (" your number was found in ",number_of_searches, "searches")
```

This will get into an infinite loop if you try to look for 101 though. So just set max to be 1 more than the actual max you want to be able to search for.

Comment: wow! That's brilliant. SO simple. Thanks a lot bro